Performance Optimization in DeblurGANv2
---
project: deblur_gan
experiment_desc: 11_50_fpn_stop

train:
#  files_a: &FILES_A /datasets/my_dataset/**/*.jpg
  #可以使用绝对路径
  #files_a: &FILES_A D:/deblur/goprol_large/**/*.png
  #files_a: &FILES_A  C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/DeblurGANv2-master/test_img/GOPRO/GOPRO_3840FPS_AVG_3-21/train/blur/**/*.png
  files_a: &FILES_A D:/deblur/blur_11/*.jpg
  files_b: &FILES_B D:/deblur/img_align_celeba/*.jpg
#  files_b: &FILES_B ./dataset1/sharp/*.png
  size: &SIZE 256
  crop: random
  preload: &PRELOAD false
  preload_size: &PRELOAD_SIZE 0
  bounds: [0, .8]
  scope: geometric
  corrupt: &CORRUPT
    - name: cutout
      prob: 0.5
      num_holes: 3
      max_h_size: 25
      max_w_size: 25
    - name: jpeg
      quality_lower: 70
      quality_upper: 90
    - name: motion_blur
    - name: median_blur
    - name: gamma
    - name: rgb_shift
    - name: hsv_shift
    - name: sharpen

val:
  files_a: *FILES_A
  files_b: *FILES_B
#  files_a: &FILES_A
#  files_b: &FILES_B
  size: *SIZE
  scope: geometric
  crop: center
  preload: *PRELOAD
  preload_size: *PRELOAD_SIZE
  bounds: [.8, 1]
  corrupt: *CORRUPT

phase: train
warmup_num: 3
model:
  g_name: fpn_inception
  blocks: 9
  d_name: double_gan # may be no_gan, patch_gan, double_gan, multi_scale
  d_layers: 3
  content_loss: perceptual
  adv_lambda: 0.001
  disc_loss: ragan-ls
  learn_residual: True
  norm_layer: instance
  dropout: True

num_epochs: 50
train_batches_per_epoch: 1000
val_batches_per_epoch: 100
batch_size: 1
image_size: [178, 218]

optimizer:
  name: adam
  lr: 0.0001
scheduler:
  name: linear
  start_epoch: 50
  min_lr: 0.0000001

I am currently using DeblurGANv2 with a dataset of 6,000 images, training with a batch size of 1. I’ve conducted experiments with 10, 30, and 50 epochs. After restoring the images, I evaluated the performance using PSNR, SSIM, and FID metrics. However, I’ve observed the following:
As the number of epochs increases, the performance does not improve.
In some cases, the performance metrics actually decline.
Could you kindly provide guidance on which parameters I should adjust to achieve better performance with more epochs?
